# How can I integrate angular code with spring boot? How to call particular page of angular from controller?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, angular

I build angular project. pasted dist folder into the src/main/resources/static, now I am able to call index.html file from controller. But the problem is (localhost:4200/homePage?empId=1234) was starting page not able to call this page from controller.
code is below(Spring controller)

```
@RequestMapping("/homePage")
public String testMethod() {
    return "/index.html";

}
```

and index.html is like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>TestApp</title>
   <base href="/homePage">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!--link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="http://localhost:8080/homePage/styles.2e25b77c70b5269b3e1c.css"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://localhost:8080/homePage/runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js"> 
   </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" 

  src="http://localhost:8080/homePage/polyfills.b58e3c18bf0ef2973262.js"> 
  </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="http://localhost:8080/homePage/main.b4ad8245c5085d925098.js"> 
   </script>
 </body>
</html
```

want to go this page (localhost:4200/homePage?empId=1234).

Comment: You are doing correct thing by  serving  dist folder . Just implement Hash routing in angular side. So anything which is like  : (localhost:4200/#/homePage?empId=1234 will be called from angular side where as URl like : (localhost:4200/homePage?empId=1234) will be called for API

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
    {path :'personCreate', component: PersonCreateComponent},
    {path: 'personSearch', component: PersonSearchComponent},
    {path: 'PersonUpdate', component: PersonUpdateComponent},
    {path: 'serchTransfer', component: SearchTransferComponent},
    {path: 'transferRequest/:personID', component: TransferRequestComponent},
    {path: 'homePage', component: HomePageComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
  })

Comment: i already have routing in angular code

Comment: You don't have hashRouting enabled. Modify like  :  [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash: true })]

Answer (score 1):

You don't mix angular js with Spring Boot thing. 
Angular is all about frontend(Client). Defining UI and communicate with Spring Boot Application for fetching,inserting or updating resources.

Spring Boot Application will be responsible for defining REST Web services and serving the requests either it is Angular or any other technology. As REST is platform independent.

There are many ways to integrate both the Angular and Spring Boot Application,you can refer below article for more detail.

https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angular-deployment

Answer (score 0):

Your frontend works in angular and your backend works with springboot. These two alone cannot communicate with each other. You need to write a service class using typescript(preferable) to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular works only for the frontend, Spring works for the backend, they communicate through HTTP communication through the rest service, where you determine the endpoints on the backend with Spring and you call those endpoints in their Angular.